# How to build the database migration properly?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm setting up a laravel project (I'm beginner) to manage customers (a customer has many contracts and a contract has many different products). And I want to implement a CRUD method and generate pdf but I have an issue at the beginning, when I migrate my database. (this is the beginning so I guess it will hard for me...)

I wrote all my migrations (customer + contracts + products) and migrate them
customer (clients):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    class Clients extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('company');
            $table->string('email', 50);
            $table->string('phone', 15);
            $table->string('adress1', 50);
            $table->string('adress2', 50);
            $table->string('adresse3', 50);
            $table->string('pays', 20);
            $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        schema::drop('clients');
    }
}
```

Contracts (contrats)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Contrats extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contrats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
           /* $table->unsignedBigInteger('clients_name');
            $table->foreign('name')->references('name')->on('Clients'); */
            $table->string('id_dossier');
            $table->string('id_contrat');
            $table->string('id_bateau');
            $table->date('startdate');
            $table->index('startdate');
            $table->date('enddate');
            $table->index('enddate');
            $table->timestamps();
    });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        schema::drop('contrats');
    }
}
```

and products (produits)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Produits extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('produits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->foreign('name'); 
            $table->string('description', 20);
            $table->double('price');
            $table->double('taxes');
    });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
         schema::drop('produits');
    }
}
```

> Migration table created successfully.
>       Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
>       Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.03 seconds)
>       Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
>       Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.02 seconds)
>       Migrating: 2019_10_15_131435_clients
>       Migrated:  2019_10_15_131435_clients (0.01 seconds)
>       Migrating: 2019_10_15_131454_contrats
>
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'name' doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `contrats` add constraint `contrats_name_foreign` foreign key (`name`) references `Clients` (`name`))
>
> at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test04/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
>           660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>           661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>           662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>           663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>
> > 664|             throw new QueryException(
> >             665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
> >             666|             );
> >             667|         }
> >             668|
>
> Exception trace:
>
> ```
>   1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'name' doesn't exist in table")
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test04/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
>
>   2   PDOStatement::execute()
>       /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test04/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:458
>
>   Please use the argument -v to see more details.
> ```

I expect to get a good migration to going ahead with this project

Thanks in advance for your help, cheers.

Comment: `$table->string('email', 50);` It's **very** common to have email addresses longer than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

write your function up for contrats migration like this

```
Schema::create('contrats', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->Increments('id');
            $table->string('id_dossier');
            $table->string('id_contrat');
            $table->string('id_bateau');
            $table->date('startdate')->index();
            $table->date('enddate')->index();
            $table->timestamps();
    });
```